# Can I get all of requestMapping URL with GET method in the Spring?

Tags: spring, url, get, sitemap, sitemap.xml

I want to make a sitemap.xml file dynamically.
If then I need to get all of url address in the controller,
How can I resolve this kinds of thing?

All I want to do is to generate sitemap.xml with spring.

The sitemap.xml have all the url that a search engine should crawl on my site 
and that's why I need this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code extracts all `RequestMappingInfo` instances from type and method-level `@RequestMapping` annotations in `@Controller` classes.

```
// context = ApplicationContext
Map<String, RequestMappingHandlerMapping> matchingBeans = BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(context,
    RequestMappingHandlerMapping.class, true, false);

if (!matchingBeans.isEmpty()) {
    ArrayList<HandlerMapping> handlerMappings = new ArrayList<HandlerMapping>(matchingBeans.values());
    AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(handlerMappings);

    RequestMappingHandlerMapping mappings = matchingBeans.get("requestMappingHandlerMapping");
    Map<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> handlerMethods = mappings.getHandlerMethods();

    for (RequestMappingInfo requestMappingInfo : handlerMethods.keySet()) {
        RequestMethodsRequestCondition methods = requestMappingInfo.getMethodsCondition();

        // Get all requestMappingInfos with 
        //  1) default request-method (which is none) 
        //  2) or method=GET
        if (methods.getMethods().isEmpty() || methods.getMethods().contains(RequestMethod.GET)) {
            System.out.println(requestMappingInfo.getPatternsCondition().getPatterns() + " -> produces " +
                    requestMappingInfo.getProducesCondition());
        }
    }
}
```

You probably need to filter out mappings for the error-pages.
The `RequestMappingInfo` object contains all the relevant mapping information that you define over `@RequestMapping` annotations such as:

- `RequestMappingInfo.getMethods()` -> `@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)`
- `RequestMappingInfo.getPatternsCondition().getPatterns()` -> `@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")`
- etc. for more details see [`RequestMappingInfo`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/RequestMappingInfo.html)

---

To further catch eg. [ViewController](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller) configurations as well, you need to filter for the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` type:

```
Map<String, SimpleUrlHandlerMapping> matchingUrlHandlerMappingBeans = BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(context,
            SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.class, true, false);
SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mappings = matchingUrlHandlerMappingBeans.get("viewControllerHandlerMapping");
System.out.println(mappings.getUrlMap());
```

Comment: Glad I could help!