# Debugging AJAX to Spring Controller (count of variables and spelling)

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am spending a lot of effort debugging ajax calls. The common issues are

- number of parameters dont match from the ajax to the controller
- spelling of the `@RequestMapping` parameter does not match

If the type does not match the call happens and it can be debugged. But the bigger issue is the above two. I have 88 parameters that I am passing and have a hell of a time trying to figure out what is missing or spelt incorrectly.

example

```
@RequestMapping("/saveClient")
    public @ResponseBody String saveClientAJAXMethodView(@RequestParam(value = "clientName") String clientName,
.... 88 parameters more

$
    .ajax({
        type : "Post",
        url : "saveClient",
        data : {
            clientName : clientName,                        
... 88 parameters more
```

I got this error

> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

So I changed the signature of my controller to add `, method = RequestMethod.POST)`.

Now I am getting

> message Request method 'GET' not supported
>   description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.

Its clearly a "POST" and still it get a request method `GET` not supported.

The question is **NOT** how to solve this problem. The question is how to debug such issues easily. What errors map to what issues, how to debug the 88 parameter spellings and count ? There must be a easier way to do this debugging.

I use the following

- Debugging Mode of the controller
- Inspect on Chrome.

Comment: Why you are sending huge amount of parameter in URL . Since you have changed your request to `POST` send it in body from your front end and in your backend use `@RequestBody`  to get body detail

Comment: you mean, change all `@RequesParam`'s to `@RequestBody`

Comment: For all Request param you have to create a DTO and use that DTO with `@RequestBody` .

Comment: That means changing design. I just need a compile time error to point out a error.

Comment: I think it would be better if i post my answer

Comment: Yeah, basically in java if I pass 2 parameters for a 3 parameters method I get a compile time error. Shouldn't a ajax call too have that :).. As I ask that I feel silly.. Its a REST call, remote.. damn.. am I even asking the right question..

Answer (score 1):

I hope following steps would help you debug:

1- Use a filter to intercept request.

2- Create a custom annotation which would indicate that you want to debug this method.

3- Use the method defined in this post [Can I get all of requestMapping URL with GET method in the Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102231/can-i-get-all-of-requestmapping-url-with-get-method-in-the-spring) and your custom annotation to store list of all methods which you want to debug in a singleton bean.

4- Now write some logic in filter which would print mismatch between the method parameters and request parameters.

CustomFilter:

```
public class CustomFilter extends GenericFilterBean {    

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("printMismatchMethods")
    HashMap<String,Method> methodsToCheck; 

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response,
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

        HttpServletRequest r = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String url = r.getRequestURI().substring(r.getContextPath().length());
        //Remove extensions if present any
        int index = url.indexOf('.');
        if(index > 0)
            url = url.substring(0,url.indexOf('.'));

        /*Matching string this should be replaced by url pattern matching of spring.*/
        if (methodsToCheck.containsKey(url)){


            Method method = methodsToCheck.get(url);

            Map<String, String[]> requestParameterMap = r.getParameterMap();
            Map<String,Boolean> isParamPresent = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();

            for (Parameter parameter : method.getParameters()){
                RequestParam requestParam = parameter.getAnnotation(RequestParam.class);

                if (requestParam != null && requestParam.required()){
                    if (!requestParam.name().isEmpty())
                        isParamPresent.put(requestParam.name(), false);
                    else
                        isParamPresent.put(requestParam.value(), false);
                }

            }
            for (Parameter parameter : method.getParameters()){
                RequestParam requestParam = parameter.getAnnotation(RequestParam.class);

                if (requestParam != null && requestParam.required()){
                    String name = null;
                    if (!requestParam.name().isEmpty())
                        name=requestParam.name();
                    else
                        name=requestParam.value();

                    if (requestParameterMap.containsKey(name)){
                        isParamPresent.put(name, true);
                    }
                }
            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : isParamPresent.entrySet()){
                if (!entry.getValue()){
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " is either missing or mis-spelled");
                }
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

configured as follows:

```
http.addFilterAfter(
                  new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Declare following custom annotation.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface PrintParamMismatch {

}
```

Define following bean which would populate on startup

```
@Bean(name="printMismatchMethods")
    @Autowired
    public HashMap<String,Method> printParamMismatchMethods(BeanFactory beanFactory){

        HashMap<String,Method> methods = new HashMap<String,Method>();

        Map<String, RequestMappingHandlerMapping> matchingBeans = 
                BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(
                        (ListableBeanFactory)beanFactory,
                        RequestMappingHandlerMapping.class, true, false);

        if (!matchingBeans.isEmpty()) {
            ArrayList<HandlerMapping> handlerMappings = new ArrayList<HandlerMapping>(matchingBeans.values());
            AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(handlerMappings);

            RequestMappingHandlerMapping mappings = matchingBeans.get("requestMappingHandlerMapping");
            Map<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> handlerMethods = mappings.getHandlerMethods();

            for (Map.Entry<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> handlerMethod : handlerMethods.entrySet()){
                RequestMappingInfo info = handlerMethod.getKey();
                HandlerMethod hMethod = handlerMethod.getValue();
                Method method = hMethod.getMethod();
                if (method.getAnnotation(PrintParamMismatch.class) != null){
                    String path = info.getPatternsCondition().toString();
                    path = path.substring(1,path.length());
                    path = path.substring(0,path.length()-1);
                    methods.put(path, method);
                }
            }
        }

        return methods;
    }
```

This, I think is generic enough to show debug information for now. However we need to store and match Patterns instead of url string.

Comment: I debugged the authenticationfilter and tried to debug into the "request" object, I found a ascii array on `postData`, how to check what key value pairs are [99, 108, 105, 101, 110, 116, 78, 97, 109, 101, 61, 66, 105, 97, 110, 99, 97, 32, 87, 104, 105, 116, 101, 104, 101, 97, 100, 38, 102, 105, 114, 115, 116..... I wonder how to decode this

Comment: Check my updated answer. I have tested a custom filter and it seems you can read parameter names and parameter values.

Comment: This worked. But I still have to manually compare the variables and their spellings. Isn't there some kind of support from the eclipse tool on this ? At the end of the day its a method being called with parameters.

Comment: see my updated answer. its a generic implementation and you just have to annotate the method of which you want to see debugging information with @PrintParamMismatch

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending huge amount of parameter in URL for POST request. I would suggest you to send your data in body.

For example if you are sending parameters like clientId, clientName, clientEmail etc.. you have used `@RequestParam` annotation to get individual parameter data in your controller:

```
String saveClientAJAXMethodView( @RequestParam String clientId,
                                 @RequestParam String clientName,
                                 @RequestParam String clientEmail
                                 .... more parameters)
```

Instead of using `@RequestParam` I would suggest you to use `@RequestBody`, For this you need to create a Data transfer object (DTO) like this:

```
class ClientInfo{
  String clientId,
  String clientName,
  String clientEmail,
  ....
  .... other variables
  .... getters and setters of variables
}
```

And then use this DTO in your controller method like this:

```
String saveClientAJAXMethodView(@RequestBody ClientInfo clientInfo){

}
```

Using this approach you will not get any exception regarding spelling mistake or parameter missing .The value will be assigned to a DTO variable if you are sending value with right key as specified in DTO.

To count variables in `ClientInfo` object you will need to `cast ClientInfo to JSONObject` and use its `size()` method to get count of variables

```
String saveClientAJAXMethodView(@RequestBody ClientInfo clientInfo){
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(clientInfo);
    System.out.println(json.keySet().size());
}
```

Your ajax call will look like this:

```
var clientInfo = {
    'clientName': 'tom',
    'clientId': '23AZ1',
    'clientEmail': 'xyz@gmail.com',
    ...
};

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(clientInfo),
    contentType: "application/json",
    complete: callback
});
```

Comment: what does the ajax to look like in this case ? can you please clarify that too so that the answer is clear..

Answer (score 0):

So I used divide and rule and solved my issue. I commented top half of the parameters and ran, to check if my controller gets called. It did. then I added 1/4th, then 1/8th and found that I missed a parameter.

That along with @ArsianAnjum's answer is good for debugging. @Aji's answer is the long term solution. I should be using that.